# How to set the image from drawable folder to imageview using the path of the image from sqlite database?

Tags: android, image, imageview, drawable, sqlite

anyone knows how to set the image from drawable folder to imageview using the path of the image from sqlite database? 
Any help will be appreciated. Sample codes will be helpful. Thanks. =)

Comment: If the image is in your drawable folder then you should set it using its id, something like `R.drawable.your_img` you shouldn't need its path. Can you elaborate a little more on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

String test = "imageName"; // store only image name in database(means not   store "R.drawable.image") like "image".
            int id = getResources().getIdentifier("projectPackageName:drawable/" + test, null, null);
            imageView.setImageResource(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get Bitmap object from file,and use it to set your image view.
Here code:

```
    String img_path = get from your database
    ...
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(img_path);
    //use it.
    yourimgview.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

^_^